# Adding worksheet to a Work Queue, but it keeps blank

Tags: blueprism

[image]

I'm getting a worksheet as Collection, then I add it to a queue, and it "works fine", but when I look in the collection I see a lot of informations, and a lot of rows (more than in the worksheet, I don't know why), and when I look in the queue it is only with one empty row, therefore, presenting the same columns titles as in the collection.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get Next Item is retrieving a blank item because you're adding items with blank fields into the work queue.

The reason there are blank rows in your Excel data is because the Get Worksheet As Collection stage is pulling everything from A1 to the last used cell in the worksheet (if you open the file in Excel, hit Ctrl+End and it'll bring you to the last used cell; this is the range that Blue Prism will be pulling).

So because you're queuing blank rows, and because Get Next Item pulls items one at a time out of the work queue, it will end up pulling those blank rows.

I'd suggest either fixing the input - remove the blank rows on the Excel sheet - or use the Collection Manipulation object to remove empty rows before adding them to the work queue.

Comment: It worked! There was a cell with some content, very hide. Thank you!!

Comment: I did what you suggest me to do, and it removed the blank rows in the collection, but even so keeps sending a blank row in collection QueueData (which comes from the "Get Next Item").

Comment: Did you clear the work queue before adding more items? It may be pulling blank items from your previous attempts. Keep in mind that work queue data is persistent outside of the process.